# jspdf: how to clip region/shapes?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to draw some shapes and lines in a restricted area.

http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#clip

The docs says there is a clip() method, but how can I achieve this exactly? And after I have clipped to shapes, is it possible to draw again outside of the clipping region? (so back to normal)

A clear example would be appreciated. Thank you.

I am using jspdf in combo with jspdf-autotable.

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error, I have found a solution:

```
    pdf.saveGraphicsState(); // pdf.internal.write('q');
    
    // draw clipping objects
    pdf.rect(0, 0, 100, 100, null); // important: style parameter is null!
    pdf.clip();

    // draw objects that need to be clipped
    pdf.setFillColor('#f54f44');
    pdf.rect(0, 0, 100, 100, 'F');

    pdf.setFillColor('#54ff54');
    pdf.rect(50, 50, 100, 100, 'F');

     // restores the state to where there was no clipping
    pdf.restoreGraphicsState(); // pdf.internal.write('Q');

    // these objects will not be clipped
    pdf.setFillColor('#001100');
    pdf.rect(80, 80, 100, 100, 'F');
```